# Selecting The bottom layer Photoshop (Shortcut)

Tags: adobe-photoshop, layers

Is there a shortcut (+click) to select a bottom layer that is fully behind a top layer in photoshop.

Ex (PSD attached): I would like to select the green circle without jumping to layers panel.

[Download the PSD](https://www.dropbox.com/s/jw0q3namxw82tk8/example.psd?dl=0)

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can press <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>[</kbd> or <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>]</kbd> to swap between layers. Just tried also you can press <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>,</kbd> to go to the bottom layer or <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>.</kbd> to go to the top layer. (<kbd>Alt</kbd> + comma, <kbd>Alt</kbd> + period)

Comment: No problem @Ahmed, hope this helps cut some time out!

Comment: @Ahmed if this answer is on target, which appears to be, you can mark it as accepted answer by clicking on the proper box next to the answer.